# Error message with a priori function in R - can not coerce list with transactions

Tags: r, transactions, apriori, coerce

I am new to stackoverflow so please take that into consideration when reading my question... thank you for your help.

I am trying to run the a priori function in R, but get the error:

> cannot coerce list with transactions with duplicated names

I don't know if it is an issue with the way my data is formatted in the CSV file, or if I am missing a step in the program.

1. Load CSV file
2. `mydata<-lapply(mydata, as.factor)`
3. `rules<-apriori(mydata,parameter=list(supp=.01,conf=.7))`

> Error in asMethod(object) : can not coerce list with transactions with
>   duplicated item

My data is formatted as a list of transactions with 1 or 0 for each product available (column):

```
product1....product15

1                 1

1                 0

0                 0

1                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your data set from integer to factor column by column.
So change your second step to:

```
for (i in 1:15){
  mydata[,i]<-as.factor(mydata[,i])
}
```